# Binary Serialization Using Boost and uint8_t

Tags: c++, boost, binary-serialization, binary-deserialization

When working with binary data I tend to use `uint8_t`. I guess that just seems like the type of a byte to me. However, I can't figure out how to get the binary serialization in boost to work with that type. Am I asking the impossible or just missing something simple?

This example program doesn't compile on VS2013 with some complaint about not being about to convert the streams into `std::ostream` or `std::istream`.

The program works fine with `char` instead of `uint8_t`, but that bugs me. :)

```
#include <cstdlib> // EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <vector>

#include "boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp"
#include "boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp"
#include "boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp"
#include "boost/iostreams/device/back_inserter.hpp"
#include "boost/iostreams/stream_buffer.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   typedef std::vector< uint8_t > Buffer;
   Buffer buffer;

   // Serialization
   {
      int foo = 1;

      typedef boost::iostreams::back_insert_device< Buffer > Device;
      Device device(buffer);

      typedef boost::iostreams::stream_buffer< Device > Stream;
      Stream stream(device);

      {
         boost::archive::binary_oarchive archive(stream);
         archive << foo;
      }
   }

   // Deserialization
   {
      int foo;

      typedef boost::iostreams::basic_array_source< uint8_t > Device;
      Device device(buffer.data(), buffer.size());

      typedef boost::iostreams::stream_buffer< Device > Stream;
      Stream stream(device);

      {
         boost::archive::binary_iarchive archive(stream);
         archive >> foo;
      }
   }

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The binary archives take a `std::istream` / `std::ostream` argument, so you're stuck using `std::basic_istream<char>` / `std::basic_ostream<char>`.

Incidentally there's no guarantee that implementations offer `unsigned char` / `uint8_t` versions of streams (or rather `std::char_traits<unsigned char>`).

Comment: This is spot on, on both paragraphs. So, indeed, just use normal streams. It's the archive's job to encode the information properly.